# Adding file groups to database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, filegroup

How can I add new file groups to an existing database in Microsoft SQL Server 2008?

I see that this is not possible through SSMS?

Answer (score 2):

You can add filegroups directly from SSMS. Right-click on a database and go to Properties.
In the Database Properties dialog under the Filegroups tab click the Add button and name your filegroup:

[image]

To add files to a filegroup, under the Files tab click the Add button and choose the filegroup to which you want to add a file:

[image]

You can also use T-SQL e.g.:

```
ALTER DATABASE [AdventureWorks2012] ADD FILEGROUP [2014]
GO
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS, right-click on your database name and choose "Properties." Select the "Filegroups" page. There's an <kbd>Add</kbd> button under the Rows section.